# What is the best strategy for calling Stored procedure in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures, repository-design

I am using repository pattern in ASP.NET MVC3.  I am extracting data through a stored procedure.

Should I create a different repository for each stored procedure or just create a single REPOSITORY class for all the procedures?

I can't embed them in Table classes as few of them gets data from two or more tables.

So what can be best option as per the Good repository pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Repositories should handle a model and it's aggregates. It doesn't matter of you use plain SQL or a SP to fetch those.

In other words: The method used to fetch objects are not important. It can be SQL statements, stored procedures, web services or whatever.

What's important is that you group objects the belong together and put them in the same repository class. The classical example is `Order` and `OrderLine`.

Comment: Thank You so Much ! I totally agree with you.                        I got your point that method are not important.                      I am using entity framework in MVC model and i am importing my database to create classes. I got many tables For Example tblQuestiions,tblVendors,tblQuotas .I have created different repository for each table.Now there is one stored procedure which gets the data from tblQuestions And tblVendors.So in which repository i should put that.

Comment: three repos since questions, vendors and quotas doesn't belong together.

Comment: Ok.Where should i Put the Stored procedure which is using all three.... what i am thinking is I should go with the Controller one to one mapping with repository What do you say ?